# ASP.NET: Download PowerPoint file with Save As

Tags: asp.net, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

I'm generating a PowerPoint file using  [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/18/creating-a-presentation-report-based-on-data.aspx) as reference. A user can search other users based on many criterias. Information based on the user is saved in the PowerPoint file. But I can't save all PowerPoint files on the server.

So, the user needs to right click a link, choose "Save As...", and save the file locally.

Nothing should be saved on the server. I have been Googling, but I'm not sure what to look for. Can you please point out a good tutorial?

I seems I am a bad googler. I removed "powerpoint" from my search string, and there are a lot of hits. But still, any comment is appreciated.

Comment: This question needs a openxml-sdk tag

Answer (score 2):

You should get file as a stream, open it using open xml sdk (You need to have Open XML SDK: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110513012228/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0)).

If you are not familiar with Open XML SDK, you can also look at the blog post [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101232551/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/04/06/zeyad-rajabi-s-open-xml-sdk-blog-map.aspx) which is also taken from the blog you already referenced.

Below code is a sample code how I create report and send to client using Open XML SDK with ASP.NET. I hope it can be helpful.

```
public void SendReport()
{
    using (Stream stream = GetReportStream())
    {
        stream.Position = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pptx");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report;");

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
}

private Stream GetReportStream()
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream file = File.Open(@"TemplateFileLocation", FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];
        file.Read(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
        // Doing manipulations explained in your reference document link.

        presentationDocument.PresentationPart.Presentation.Save();
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Don't forget to download and check the whole solution on the link you referenced.

Comment: Ok, Musa. It looks good. I have combined the code from the url I posted with your suggestion. I need to test a little more, but Im sure I have found what I was looking for. Thank you.......